# Reading svn commit messages from the console

Tags: svn, command-line

What's the command line way to get the commit messages for a given revision?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

svn log — Display commit log messages. This should work with the switch -r or --revision to display commit message for a particular revision

```
svn log --revision 16
```

- http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re15.html

Comment: The -v option also prints the changed paths.

Answer (score 3):

Once I needed to display log message on the **SVN server side** (in my svn hook) by a given repository path on the computer. For this case you can use:

```
 svnlook -r 105 log C:\Repositories\unit-tests-repo
```

I know, that you asked the question 8 years ago, but probably my answer can help another people.